# std::string initialization using + in the initializer

Tags: c++, initialization, stdstring

I am not sure what I am missing here, but following is my code and `version2` works fine and `version1` has some junk value printed on screen. I am not sure why `version1` isn't getting initialized as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define MAJOR_VERSION "4"
#define MINOR_VERSION "1"

int main()
{
    std::string version1{ MAJOR_VERSION[0] + "." + MINOR_VERSION[0] };
    std::string version2{ MAJOR_VERSION[0] };
    version2 += ".";
    version2 += MINOR_VERSION[0];

    std::cout << version1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << version2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with initializing the std::string this way (referring to `version1` initialization)?

Comment: `"."` is a c-string, not a `std::string`.  You can't use `+` to concatenate them.  Looking for a duplicate

Comment: You are adding chars (integers) and pointers, not strings.

Comment: Fun fact: Compile time c-strings auto-concat if they are next to each other. So: `"Hello World"` and `"Hello " "World` compile the same. So, since all your strings are c-strings, you could just do: `std::string version{MAJOR_VERSION "." MINOR_VERSION}` (no `+`). BUT! This only works when they are defined at compile time.

Comment: As mentioned in the linked question's accepted answer, it makes sense to use the + operator that can work with `std::string` and `const char*`. So I just did `std::string version1 { MAJOR_VERSION + std::string{"."} + MINOR_VERSION };` and that worked. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It's not yet a string initialization. You try to add two `char const*` pointers, that doesn't work. Instead, you might convert the first to string first:

```
    std::string version1{ std::string(MAJOR_VERSION) + "." + MINOR_VERSION };
```

or, even better:

```
    auto version1 = std::string(MAJOR_VERSION) + "." + MINOR_VERSION;
```

Comment: Their initialization attempt actually adds a `char` to a `const char*` to a `char`. So it "works" in that it is valid syntax and compiles but the result is Undefined Behavior due to accessing a far out of bounds element of `"."`. They don't add two `const char *` together.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for spotting, removed the array subscripts.